# PyMongo - Delete documents based on a date condition where date is stored in string format (%m/%d/%y) in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, python-requests, pymongo

How to delete Mongodb documents based on certain date condition using PyMongo which stores the date object in string format in MongoDB ?

Sample code:

API takes a date parameter as payload and returns only that much data.So before inserting new documents, want to ensure previous data is not delete and only the ones which are being currently processed.

```
import requests
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

past_4_month= datetime.today() + relativedelta(months=-4)
past_4_month_1st_day=past_4_month.strftime("%m/01/%Y")

url='xxx'
header={'Auth':'xyz', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload={'start_date': past_4_month_1st_day }
api_data = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=header).json()

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017') 
db = client[test_db][test_collection]

db.delete_many({'date':{'$gte':past_4_month_1st_day}})

db.insert_many(api_data)

client.close()
```

Sample output stored in mongodb:

```
{
 "id": ObjectId("5f44e33ffb3be4ed19a10ed3"), 
 "xyz_id" : "12345", 
 "name" : "xyz", 
 "date" : "3/3/2020"
}
```

For example - when running in Aug-2020 - it will return data from past 4 months i.e. May-2020 onwards and always truncate/delete and load same data until end of Aug-2020.

On Sep-2020 1st of the month, the prev 4 month date would be June-2020, so it should not delete May-2020 data but only from June-2020 till current month (Sep-2020). Meaning only process past 4 months data always with every run (truncate/delete and reload).

However, since the date is stored as string in MongoDB document, tried using converting it to date from string using $dateFromString, $toDate and in Python etc. it is still not working as expected and deletes all the documents (from May-2020) from previous runs/loads.

Please suggest.

Comment: Add another field to your documents where the date is stored sensibly (either using YYYY-MM-DD syntax or using an actual timestamp), then use that field for queries.

Comment: this could be a workaround, but was looking for an ideal solution.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible to construct   regular expressions that would match m/d/y date ranges.